# Does IBM Worklight 6.1.0 supports Blackberry 10.2?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-studio

I just need a clarification of Blackberry support for 10.2 OS.

I know Worklight supports Blackberry 10.

I have tried to install worklight application on Blackberry 10.2[Z30] but not getting installed.

SDK:       Blackberry SDK 1.0.4.11
Device:    Blackberry Z30 [OS 10.2.0.1521]
Worklight: IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1

Does worklight supports BB10.2. If it's so suggest me a way to implement worklight applications on Blackberry Z30.

Thanks 
Sundar

Comment: What is "not working"? You'll have to try better than that and properly explain yourself.

Comment: @IdanAdar, I hope you read the question "I have tried to install worklight application on Blackberry 10.2[Z30] but not getting installed." Application not getting deployed in Blackberry Z30 device.

Comment: No. The status code in Ripple service says 200.

Comment: As far as the documents of 6.1 there is no saying that it supports BB 10.2. but the worklight 6.2 have complete support for BB 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Blackberry 10.2 is listed as a supported OS in the [System Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838) for Worklight 6.1. As Idan suggested, please provide more details to assist with debug. What steps did you take? Have you tried it on other blackberry devices? Other OS? Have you tried a simple hello-world type app? Have you searched the BB forums? Lots of posts there about the App error 200, including a corrupted application.

Comment: Barbara, I was getting the following as a result. Done build
Build complete, now deploying...
>>> EXEC "C:/Program Files/Research In Motion/BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11/dependencies/tools/bin/blackberry-deploy.bat" -installApp -launchApp -device 169.254.10.13169.254.10.13 -password 123456 "C:/BAR/device/app.bar"
2014-06-08 17:59:45 GET /ripple/build_status/273 200. But app was not deployed in BB10.2

Comment: I don't understand. See questions above.

Comment: 1. The link you shared was unable to access. 2.Steps I have taken which was in the IBM Worklight 6.1 Modules. 3. Yes, I have tried with Blackberry Z10 and its working fine. 4. The app what I am trying to deploy is Helloworld. 5. I have searched in BB Forum the steps was highlighted as same as IBM Worklight doc.